# Why is SSIS 2012 removing my password from my connection string parameter?

Tags: ssis

I have a password in my connection string in my SSIS package.  I created a project parameter for the connection string and used Parameterize on the Package Connection Manager to use it.

[image]

If I try to run the step I get a "Login failed for user.." error.

When I go back and look at the Parameterize, the connection string value shows the password removed.

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: To restate: When your package is in SSDT, you have a password. When you deploy and run from the server, you have no password?

Comment: When I'm running the package from Visual Studio 2012 I have no password.

Comment: What is your project/package ProtectionLevel (right click on the background of the control flow, select Properties. Find Protection Level in the Properties window)

Comment: It was at the default of EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey but I've also tried EncryptAllWithUserKey.  I get the same behavior with either setting which is the password not being saved.  This is not a deployment issue.  I'm trying to develop a new package in Visual Studio 2012 and all I want to do is have the password saved while I develop.

Comment: Have you tried setting the connection string an an expression of the connection manager properties... This is not exactly safe for deployment but it would atleast get you thru development

Comment: That does not work either.  I have tried to manually add ;Password= to the end of the ConnectionString property.  As soon as I tab or mouse off the textbox, it removes the password.   I also tried clicking on the ellipse and use the Connection Manager srreen and of course that does not save the password even though "Save my password" is checked.